# how to write byte[] to Image with Landscape or Portrait properties?

Tags: c#-4.0, image-processing, bitmap, memorystream

I have a code which converts byte[] to image but my code always writes in Landscape mode even original image was Portrait. How can I detect original image's Page Orientation and write new Image with this properties? Any suggestions?

```
public void SendFax(byte[] file, string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(file);
            Image imgSave = Image.FromStream(ms);
            Bitmap bmSave = new Bitmap(imgSave);
            Bitmap bmTemp = new Bitmap(bmSave);
            Graphics grSave = Graphics.FromImage(bmTemp);
            grSave.DrawImage(imgSave, 0, 0, imgSave.Width, imgSave.Height)

            //Save Image to physical path
            bmTemp.Save("C:/..." + fileName);

            imgSave.Dispose();
            bmSave.Dispose();
            bmTemp.Dispose();
            grSave.Dispose();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this. Check for img height and width and based on the comparison decide portrait/landscape

```
int srcWidth = image.Width;
int srcHeight = image.Height;
int thumbWidth = width;
int thumbHeight;
Bitmap bmp;
if (srcHeight > srcWidth)
{
    thumbHeight = (srcHeight / srcWidth) * thumbWidth;
    bmp = new Bitmap(thumbWidth, thumbHeight);
}
else
{
    thumbHeight = thumbWidth;
    thumbWidth = (srcWidth / srcHeight) * thumbHeight;
    bmp = new Bitmap(thumbWidth, thumbHeight);
}
```